# How to remove white related colors in KnowColor C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcellstyle

Currently im using this method for generating randomized KnownColor used for DataGriView cell background-color.

```
    public static Color GetRandomizedKnownColor()
    {
        Random randomGen = new Random();
        KnownColor[] names = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
        KnownColor randomColorName = names[randomGen.Next(names.Length)];
        Color randomColor = Color.FromKnownColor(randomColorName);
        return randomColor;
    }
```

Now i want to remove all white related KnowColors so that all possible generated color is not in contrast with the white DataGriView cell background-color in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
static private Random randomGen = new Random();
public static Color GetRandomizedKnownColor()
{
    int number;
    do
    {
        number = randomGen.Next(28, 168);
    } while (number == (int)KnownColor.White);

    return Color.FromKnownColor((KnownColor)number);
}
```

Note that your `Random` object will always return the same value in your code.

`KnownColor` elements from 28 to 167 are actual colors while the rest refer to control colors (like `ActiveCaptionText`, `InactiveBorder`, etc). If you actually want *all KnownColors* and skip all white colors (there are other [255,255,255] besides "White"), you should use this code instead:

```
Color randomColor;
do
{
    randomColor = Color.FromKnownColor((KnownColor)randomGen.Next(1, 175));
} while (randomColor.R + randomColor.G + randomColor.B == 255 * 3);
return randomColor;
```

If you want to skip also very light colors, you can use a condition like this, for example:

```
} while (randomColor.R + randomColor.G + randomColor.B >= 250 * 3);
```

Comment: I'm glad to read that. Please note that if you used my second example, the number range was wrong. I just corrected it.

Comment: Yes i did it experimentally and ive got numbers of knowncolor definition, Big thanks!

Comment: Didn't you just right click and choose "Go to definition" (or press F12) to find all the numbers?

Comment: Oh i see, this is how you determine the coloring numbers! How helpful!